# Script recording in Mac Ventura is not working.Getting No Internet Access as soon as the URL is launched in Jmeter Chrome

Tags: macos, jmeter, macos-ventura

Script recording in Mac Ventura is not working.Getting No Internet Access as soon as the URL is launched in Jmeter Chrome. Added proxy settings image. Can somebody help please.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome uses **system-wide proxy settings** which means that you're changing proxy settings for MacOS and it might break your computer Internet connectivity.

Try using another browser for recording, for example [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) has separate proxy configuration independent of the operating system.

Alternatively you can consider using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to record the script is using a browser extension such as Foxy proxy.

Guide: [Foxyproxy](https://help.observepoint.com/article/154-foxyproxy-extension-configuring-the-liveconnect-proxy)

Configure the proxy and start your record - in this way you won't lose the internet connection